# what is System.out or systemout in php?

Tags: php

i was exploring php and i found **system.out** and **systemout**. 
php says that's they are strings, but they don't act like strings. 
Here are some examples.

```
    system.out.print('test');
    //output
    test

    system.out.var_dump('system.out');
    // output
    string(9) "systemout"


    systemout.var_dump('test');
    // output 

string(4) "test"
```

is this a language error ?

Comment: @lix yes it's php try it..

Comment: no.. It's not valid PHP in anycase...

Comment: You'll receive a nice notice 
`Notice: Use of undefined constant system - assumed 'system'` and
`Notice: Use of undefined constant out - assumed 'out'`. I'm not sure what you mean by, "they don't act like strings". Realistically you would just use `print('test');`

Comment: This definitely looks like PHP code that got into production somehow. Should have ended on TDWTF instead of SO though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me say this in code:

```
in.fact.you.can.concat.many.undefined.constants.with.any.func.print('.');
```

If you have error reporting enabled, php will inform you about many undefined constants, and they will be treated as strings, so it will be treated as:

```
'in'.'fact'.'you'.'can'.'concat'.'many'.'undefined'.'constants'.'with'.'any'.'func'.print('.');
```

And the only thing that produces desired output is function call. The return value of this function is concatenated to the string of undefined constants and does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

```
//i can tell what you are trying to do.is to dumb some vars to console.
//System.out.printLn does not exist in php

//there are other tools like firephp but this is the simplest method to log vars to console
//use the following function instead in php
function phpconsole($label='var',$x){
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   console.log('<?php echo ($label)?>');
   console.log('<?php echo json_encode($x)?>');
  </script>
 <?php
}
//use it like this
$salary = 500;
phpconsole('salary:',$salary);

$arr = array('aaa','bbb','ccc');
phpconsole('arr:',$arr);//it will accept any datatype and dumb it to console
```

Comment: You have got to be kidding me, He said PHP, he didn't say he needs it for a web page. and even if it was for a web-page. The code above is dinosauric! no-offense.

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.jansch.nl/2007/03/09/systemoutprint-in-php/ ..professionals just write the logic behind what they say.Your comment should begin with "He said PHP,..."

Comment: Brother, the link you gave is extremely outdated (2015-2007=8), and I don't find the information on that page very useful to be true. Also My point was that I make PHP CLI apps, how is this supposed to work in CLI?

Comment: By the way FirePHP uses headers, which don't hurt output buffering at all. If someone uses this console.log method and then tries the header() function, he'll get fatal error that headers have already been sent. I know that this can be resolved with output buffering, but that would be a hack though. Means, it's not a good or even a way of doing it :-)